# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

This project is working on other devices but when I run it on my, It is giving this error.
Note: C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-0.3.7+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\androidintent\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     216.9s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:label="label">
    
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="Key"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```